# Stripping text with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm a newbie with javascript and I was wondering how do I strip all the text except the word **TB_iframeContent800** . the digits at the end varies.

here is an example string

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 670px; height: 401px;" onload="tb_showIframe()" name="TB_iframeContent80" id="TB_iframeContent" src="http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=33&amp;" hspace="0">This feature requires inline frames. You have iframes disabled or your browser does not support them.</iframe>
```

I want to extract **TB_iframeContent80** and store it as a variable. So how can you do this using regex with javascript? please note the last 2 digits varies cause the number always changes so it sometimes become a 3 digit number.

Comment: are you trying to extract iframe name?

Comment: Please just use JavaScript's DOM manipulation and not regex.

Comment: yes I'm trying to extract the iframe name

Comment: Then using the DOM functionality would be semantically correct, and easier to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var iframeName = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].name
```

if you've include jQuery then it could be something like this:

```
 var iframeName = $("iframe:first").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is an option I think you are looking for something like this

`$('iframe[name^="TB_iframeContent"]')`

Answer (score 1):

If you wont use DOM (because code analysis etc) just try this regex

```
var code = '<iframe ... /iframe>';

var result = code.match( /name="([^"]*)"/ );

var extract = result[1];
```

this selects the content of the name attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could load html youre parsing like this and use DOM to get its name (its easier and more reliable way than using a regex):

```
var loadhtml = document.createElement('div');
loadhtml.innerHTML = 'yourHtml';

var theName = loadhtml.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].name;
```

If you use Jquery you could consider attr("name") as way to get name

However if you insist using a Regex here is one :

```
/< *iframe[^>]*name *= *['"]([^'"]*)/
```